# invalid argument supplied foreach (wp instagram widget)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget, instagram

I'm having an issue with the wp instagram widget. I'm getting an error that says

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()... on line 203.

Here's line 203:

```
if (!$insta_array)
            return new WP_Error('bad_json', __('Instagram has returned invalid data.', $this->cassiwdomain));

        $images = $insta_array['entry_data']['UserProfile'][0]['userMedia'];

        $instagram = array();

        foreach ($images as $image) {

            if ($image['user']['username'] == $username) {

                $image['link']                          = preg_replace( "/^http:/i", "", $image['link'] );
                $image['images']['thumbnail']           = preg_replace( "/^http:/i", "", $image['images']['thumbnail'] );
                $image['images']['standard_resolution'] = preg_replace( "/^http:/i", "", $image['images']['standard_resolution'] );

                $instagram[] = array(
                    'description'   => $image['caption']['text'],
                    'link'          => $image['link'],
                    'time'          => $image['created_time'],
                    'comments'      => $image['comments']['count'],
                    'likes'         => $image['likes']['count'],
                    'thumbnail'     => $image['images']['thumbnail'],
                    'large'         => $image['images']['standard_resolution'],
                    'type'          => $image['type']
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parsed json doesn't contain an array at the path $insta_array['entry_data']['UserProfile'][0]['userMedia'];

There is no check for this before the line

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
```

You could fix the error by wrapping the foreach statement in a check such as

```
if (is_array($images)){
    //Existing foreach loop
}
```

But you would still see no images from instagram

Possibly because the instagram account doesn't have any pictures.

Can you verify that the account does in fact have pictures?

It would also be helpful if you could post the output of

```
var_dump($insta_array);
exit;
```

You can add that code just above the line

```
if (!$insta_array)
```

Comment: This is what's before that code i posted:  $instagram = array();

Comment: $instagram is not the same variable

Comment: The account does in fact have pictures